# Timeout during the verification of two array addition

Tags: c, frama-c

I am trying to verify the addition of two 2d arrays but I constantly take a timeout error regardless of the solver that I use.

The code that I am trying to verify is the following:

```
typedef struct{
  float mem[3];
}BaseMatrix3x1;


/*@ requires \valid(b1) && \valid(b2);
  @ ensures A: \forall integer i; 0 <= i < 3 ==>
                b1->mem[i] == \old(b1)->mem[i] + b2->mem[i];
  @ assigns b1->mem[0..2];
@*/
void baseMatrixAssignAdd3x1(BaseMatrix3x1 *b1, BaseMatrix3x1 *b2){
    /*@ loop invariant 0 <= i <= 3;
      loop invariant \forall integer k; 
      0 <= k < i ==>
        \at(b1->mem[k], LoopCurrent) ==
            \at(b1->mem[k], LoopEntry) + \at(b2->mem[k], LoopEntry);
      loop assigns i, b1->mem[0..2];*/ 
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<3; i++){
        b1->mem[i] += b2->mem[i];
  }
}
```

The second loop invariant is the one that causes all the solvers to timeout.

Do you have any suggestions?

**Edit**:
I fixed the assign error (which was not the problem though).

I don't call this function somewhere yet, I am just trying to prove the loop invariants. From my understanding, in order to verify a function, we do not care about the way that this function will be called. We care only about the Pre and Post conditions that we have.

Comment: How are you initializing b1 and b2, and how do you call the function?  (edit your post showing these please)

Comment: The text in the comments does not agree with what the code does. Specifically, the comments state that mem[0] through mem[3] are assigned new values, but the code sets mem[0] through mem[2] only.

Comment: @EugeneSh - I removed my _comment_ below because I agree that the question is about something other than what OP has posted.  There is no content about _static-analysis_, except the tag.  (Unless the function show is representing something other than a summing loop.)

Comment: @ryvker: this question is very much on-topic in the *static-analysis* tag. Not all static analyzers need the entire program to wok. Here, the author is attempting to prove his function at the unit level, using deductive verification.

Comment: There is no 2D array in your code!

Comment: @Olaf I'm puzzled as to why this function should be closed. The MCVE is fine, and the problem is clearly stated: the SMT solvers the OP used are timing out, meaning that the proof fails.

Comment: @byako: Any specific reason you ask **me**? The CV has more than one closer. Just that: Check times, see the history! If Feel free to OV.

Comment: Sorry if my comment was inappropriate, but I can notify only one person and you were the only one with an activity on this question. And unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation to see the CV history

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, what is incorrect/missing in your code:

- you never mention that `b1` and `b2` are pointers to *different* matrices. Your loop assigns are incorrect without this information, because `b2->mem[0..2]` also gets assigned. You need to add a `requires \separated(b1, b2);` assumption
- you postcondition is incorrect, because `\old` only applies to the *pointer* `b1` (which remains unchanged in the function anyway), while it should apply to `b1->mem`. You should have written `\old(b1->mem[i])` instead.
- you're missing an important loop invariant, namely that `b1->mem[i..2]` has not been modified (yet). Since your loop assigns mentions that all of `b1->mem` may be assigned at every iteration, you need to add an invariant on the unchanged parts.

Next, one apparent limitation of the WP plugin that prevents a full proof:

- the support for the label `LoopCurrent` seems insufficient. But, in your loop invariants, `LoopCurrent` is the default label. So you can always replace `\at(P, LoopCurrent)` by `P`.

Here is a fully annotated version of your code that the WP plugin is able to prove, using Alt-Ergo as prover.

```
/*@
  requires \valid(b1) && \valid(b2);
  requires \separated(b1, b2);
  ensures A: \forall integer i; 0 <= i < 3 ==>
                b1->mem[i] == \old(b1->mem[i]) + b2->mem[i];
  assigns b1->mem[0..2];
@*/
void baseMatrixAssignAdd3x1(BaseMatrix3x1 *b1, BaseMatrix3x1 *b2){
  /*@ loop invariant 0 <= i <= 3;
      loop invariant \forall integer k; 
        k >= i ==> b1->mem[k] == \at(b1->mem[k], Pre);
      loop invariant \forall integer k; 
        0 <= k < i ==> b1->mem[k] == \at(b1->mem[k], LoopEntry) + b2->mem[k];
      loop assigns i, b1->mem[0..2];*/ 
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<3; i++){
    b1->mem[i] += b2->mem[i];
  }
}
```